# setState of nested object in react failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below code, `nextProps.ad.submission.content` is async data

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.state.body !== get(nextProps.ad.submission.content, '')){
        this.setState({
            body: nextProps.ad && nextProps.ad.submission && nextProps.ad.submission.content
        })
    }
}
```

`get` is from lodash, why I got error of `Cannot read property 'content' of undefined`? Isn't it means `nextProps.ad && nextProps.ad.submission && nextProps.ad.submission.ad`?

Answer (score 0):

the error is at this line

```
if(this.state.body !== get(nextProps.ad.submission.content, '')){
```

means that in `nextProps.ad` you don't have property called `submission` which means `nextProps.ad.submission` is undefined and you try to access the property `content` of `undefined`

### To Solve

check if `nextProps.ad.submission` is not undefined first

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) 
{
    if(nextProps.ad.submission !== undefined)
    {
        if (this.state.body !== get(nextProps.ad.submission.content, '')) 
        {
            this.setState({
                body: nextProps.ad && nextProps.ad.submission && nextProps.ad.submission.content
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know the problem, but you don't have a solution.